# WPF DataGrid decimal format

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, decimal, string-formatting

I have a datagrid column binded to a decimal property. Its value in the database is `2100.00`

I want to show the exact same value in the datagrid column, but without any StringFormat, I get this result: `210000`.

If I apply this StringFormat:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding [Amount], StringFormat=F2}" />
```

I get this result:

```
210000.00
```

Is it any other StringFormats I could use to solve my problem?

Comment: whats the type of your [Amount]? decimal or double or ?

Comment: It's of type decimal.

Comment: does your itemssource item object has the right decimal value from 2100.00? i use StringFormat=#\,##0.00

Comment: @bale3, is value in DB also numeric? Does the `Amount` has 2100 or 210000? It looks to me like culture problem when _._ is taken as digit grouping rather then decimal separator during conversion from `String`.

Comment: The itemssource item object has this value: 2100.00. When I try your StringFormat I get this result: 210,000.00

Comment: @dkozl, the DB type is decimal(18,2) and the value in DB is 2100.00.